# how to put special symbols in google chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I used dollar sign to have a prefix in dollar but my problem is i need it to be in GBP/british pound like this "£". how can i do this? thanks

```
var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var formatted = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$'});
data2.addColumn('string', 'Company');
data2.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use the javascript \u followed by the hex code for the unicode character.

In this case \u00A3